# NullpointerException when reading text file from assests folder

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

i am trying to read the txt file which has the json format  content in it, i am using async task to read the file from the asset folder but getting nullpointer exception..below is my code.

```
public class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private MyDBAdapter dbHelper;

    String fileName = "json.txt";
     Context c;
     private static final String result = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

         readFileFromAssets(fileName,c);
        return null;

}

 public static String readFileFromAssets(String fileName, Context c) {
     AssetManager assetManager = c.getAssets();
     InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = assetManager.open(fileName);
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            String text = new String(buffer);
System.out.println("tex===========t"+ text);
            return text;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
 }
```

Below is my Log Trace

```
09-24 10:53:25.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1714): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-24 10:53:25.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):     at com.markupartist.android.actionbar.example.DownloadJSON.readFileFromAssets(DownloadJSON.java:75)
09-24 10:53:25.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):     at com.markupartist.android.actionbar.example.DownloadJSON.doInBackground(DownloadJSON.java:27)
09-24 10:53:25.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):     at com.markupartist.android.actionbar.example.DownloadJSON.doInBackground(DownloadJSON.java:1)
09-24 10:53:25.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
09-24 10:53:25.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
09-24 10:53:25.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):     ... 5 more
```

Not sure where i am doing wrong.

Comment: please post your logcat error

Comment: @dipali hi updated with log

Comment: what is `DownloadJSON.java line 75` ?

Comment: is c for your context null, i dont see it passed in anywhere

Comment: this error is for null in context.please initialize your context.

Comment: @dipali its showing error at getApplicationContext().. when initialized, asking tocreate method...???

Comment: @dipali DownloadJSON is a external class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whenever you call this `asynctask` from `activity`,then please pass `context` as a parameter.this is finally error of context.

so please right way to pass context.

I hope you understand.

Comment: hi this DownloadJson is not an activity its an external class, now how to pass context here

Comment: @pankaj what you say base on your comment?

Answer (score 3):

You are not initialized the context object that's why it is giving you `nullpointer exception` initialize it like this..

```
Context c=getApplicationContext();
```

Comment: its showing error at getApplicationContext().. when initialized, asking tocreate method...???

Comment: If it is in the activity initialize it like Context c=Activity.this;

Answer (score 2):

Problem would be on this `AssetManager assetManager = c.getAssets();` because you are not passing proper `Context`.

You are declaring `Context` but not initialize anywhere in your `AsynTask`, do something like below:

```
Context c;

c=activity.this;
```

Else if you using asyntask in same class then pass directly activity `Context` to your function.

> readFileFromAssets(fileName,activity.this);

**Updated**

Create Construction of `DownloadJSON`, get context and use same context like below:

```
  public class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
   Context ctx;
    public DownloadJSON(Context c) {
    ctx=c;

    }
```

And while calling `DownloadJSON` pass necessary `Context`.

Comment: hi this DownloadJson is not an activity its an external class, now how to pass context here

Answer (score 1):

You are getting NullPointer because of Context, Context is passing null, so make Context initialize like

Context c;
c=getApplicationContext() OR c=Activity name.this

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized your Context.. So first make your Class Constructor...

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
Context ctx;

public DownloadJSON (Context c, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.ctx = c;
    this.arraylist= list;

}
```

Finally Use this ctx object in

```
readFileFromAssets(fileName,ctx);
```

Thanks....